# What are my alternatives to disable update notifications but without using module Update Notifications Disable?

Tags: 7, updating

I need to disable the update notification overall Drupal 7, rather than downloading the module [Update Notifications Disable](https://drupal.org/project/update_notifications_disable) because it caused a fatal error, and the site went down.

Is there any other way?

Comment: I want to keep the core Update module enabled to notify user 1 of required security updates and issue the email notifications. But I don't want other admins to see the on screen messages.  None of the current answers address this.  I disabled the "Administer software updates" permission for the Administrator role.  Shouldn't that stop the messages from displaying to those users?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The method below will stop the "available update" emails Drupal admins receive.

1. Go here: http://**yourwebsite**.com/admin/reports/updates/settings
2. Remove your email(s) from the textarea: "**E-mail addresses to notify when updates are available**"
3. Save

**Note**: If you want to stop the "available updates" emails and the update alert messaging then simply disable the update module from http://**yourwebsite**.com/admin/modules

Comment: Or, in the same admin/reports/updates/settings page, you can change the email threshold to only security notifications.

Answer (score 16):

You can disable the module Update in the module list, but you will never be aware about update and security updates.

Comment: "you will never be aware about update and security updates" -I think it is true if you have only one stand-alone system. If you have multiple Drupal instances and use git, it is enough to have the Update module enabled on one box or not at all.

Answer (score 5):

you can do it with drush:

```
drush dis update
```

Comment: An explanation would be nice, since `drush dis update` not just simply disables notifications.

Answer (score 3):

You can always disable the core Update module. There is, however, no SEO impact for these messages, as the messages are displayed only to administrative users by default, unless you manually and gave anonymous users permission to see the administrative messages, you will be fine.

It would be good if you could stay updated with your drupal version for security reasons, but if you can't for some reason or just don't want to (totally understandable!) just disable the Update module. :)

Answer (score 2):

One way to keep track of updates is to enable the Update module on a development server. With the rate of security update the "There are security updates..." message practically stays up at all times.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Update Status Advanced](https://drupal.org/project/update_advanced) to disable module by module

Comment: unfortunateley not available for D8

Answer (score 1):

Use `drush dis update` or, if you not familiar with Drush, go to admin/reports/updates/settings, remove your email(s) from *E-mail addresses to notify when updates are available*, and save.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider setting your site to only notify user/1 (or admins) of security updates only.

A quick look at the results of drush vget for one of my sites revealed this interesting variable/value pair:

update_notification_threshold: 'security'

So, to only be updated when there are security updates for core, modules and themes consider setting your site's variable for this to the above using drush vset. You can also do this via the UI, if you bother to read it :)

To be clear, the command is:

drush vset update_notification_threshold 'security'

I would advise to think carefully about what you are changing and why, and to test any changes in your local, dev, stage and/or test environments prior to pushing to prod, and of course, then testing prod.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind modifying the module code (it's not good practice), comment out the line (around 155) 
`drupal_set_message($status[$type]['description'], 'error', FALSE);`.

These notices should still be logged, so consider adding
`watchdog('Security Update', $status[$type]['description'], array(), WATCHDOG_WARNING);`

```
 if (isset($status[$type])
        && isset($status[$type]['reason'])
        && $status[$type]['reason'] === UPDATE_NOT_SECURE) {
     // drupal_set_message($status[$type]['description'], 'error', FALSE);
        watchdog('Update', $status[$type]['description'], array(), WATCHDOG_WARNING, 'http://www.sourceglobalresearch.com/admin/modules/update');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If You want to remove alert message for the module update. So Go in .info file and change the Version for the module. In that cases, Some of the module unable to update Like OG group.